# OpenWISP -- inputing a certification authority

Tags: openssl, certificate-authority

We're trying to set up OpenWISP using a paid-for wildcard (*.ngv.com.au) SSL certificate.  The certificate comes to us as a ZIP of these files:

```
AAACertificateServices.crt
SectigoRSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt
star.csr
star.key
STAR_ngv_com_au.crt
USERTrustRSAAAACA.crt
```

I presume `STAR_ngv_com_au.crt` is our certificate and the other `.crt` files are the chain.

However, I cannot input an acceptable certification authority into OpenWISP.  When I enter our certificate and refer to the CA I've entered, OpenWISP responds

```
CA doesn't match, got the following error from pyOpenSSL: "unable to get local issuer certificate"
```

Following [this advice](https://serverfault.com/questions/1033987/how-to-bundle-intermediate-certs-into-one-file), my best attempt at entering the certificate of the certification authority is the output of

```
cat STAR_ngv_com_au.crt SectigoRSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt USERTrustRSAAAACA.crt AAACertificateServices.crt
```

or

```
cat SectigoRSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt USERTrustRSAAAACA.crt AAACertificateServices.crt
```

but each of those yields the *CA doesn't match* error, as does using each of the four `.crt` files individually.

What magic combination of files is required to satisfy OpenWISP/pyOpenSSL?

Comment: Exactly who are you paying, and for what? IINM Sectigo (now) transparency-logs everything and crt.sh doesn't show any '*.ngv.com.au' issued by Sectigo RSA DV-Server. It does show a series of 90-day certs issued by ZeroSSL ECC Domain, most recently this [precert](https://crt.sh/?id=11810545769) and [cert](https://crt.sh/?id=11810545994). If that is the cert you are trying to use, you need [this intermediate](https://crt.sh/?id=2427368475) not one for Sectigo, and its parent is Usertrust ECC not Usertrust RSA.

Comment: `I presume STAR_ngv_com_au.crt is our certificate and the other .crt files are the chain.` If YOU open YOUR certificate, who is the issuer? It is written right there, no presumption necessary.

Comment: We paid Crazy Domains (don't judge me;  not my choice).  I don't see how to use those links because the only option that OpenWISP provides for CA entry is copy-paste of the `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- ...` content.

Comment: Our issuer is Crazy Domains but none of the six files in the bundle  contain that information.  They contain only `----BEGIN CERTIFICATE ...`, `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY ...` etc.;  i.e., the first line of each of the six files is `-----BEGIN something` and the last line of each of the six files is `-----END something`.

Comment: @Greg Askew:  "If YOU open YOUR certificate ..." are you saying there is some software, not just a plain text editor, with which I can open a `.crt` file (presumably also supplying the `star.key` file) and decode and view the content?

Comment: Most operating systems and browsers will let you view a certificate. This is common practice for a forum of systems administrators.